# Give a folder certain permissions on App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm completely new to app engine and I need to give a certain directory in my application permission 733 How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Files uploaded with your application are accessible only by your application - or in the case of static content, by everyone, logged in users, or admins only, depending on your authentication settings. Other applications cannot access your files, so the idea of file permissions makes no sense in the context of an App Engine app.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot write to the filesystem from your application. Any dynamically created data must live in the datastore, the blobstore, or memcache.

Post some more details about what you're trying to do, and we can advise how it would be done without writing files.